# IndexError: list index out of range in CSV file reading python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file contaning 30000000 entries.
like this

```
കൃഷി 3
വ്യാപകമാകുന്നു 2
നെല്‍കൃഷി 2
വെള്ളം 2
നെല്ല് 2
മാത്രമേ 2
ജല 2
```

When I try to reverse the word order 
I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home//grpus/dg.py", line 8, in <module>
    writer.writerow((row[1], row[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the code:

```
import csv

with open('s.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    with open("revmal.txt", "w") as o:
        writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow((row[1], row[0]))
```

Edit

```
 writer.writerow(row[::-1])
```

When I try to fix it

How to fix this error?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/grpus/dg.py", line 7, in <module>
        for row in reader:
    Error: field larger than field limit (131072)
```

The file is 1.4 Gb in size

```
wc -L s.csv
```

936

```
{if(length($0)>max){max=length($0);maxline=$0}}END{print maxline} This produced
```

����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������!� 1,
186 characters

Comment: This can happen when you run into a blank line, or when one of your lines only has one column; also I realized you are simply writing the row in reverse, why not try `writer.writerow(row[::-1])`?

Comment: What is the size of this file? (The file system size).

Comment: what is the output of `wc -L s.csv`?

Comment: Hrmm, what is the output of this: `awk '{if(length($0)>max){max=length($0);maxline=$0}}END{print maxline}' s.csv`? Is it a very long line?

Comment: In the same format as your lines you pasted here?

Comment: the line you pasted, has no tab character. I believe your delimiter is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least one row that doesn't have 2 columns separated by a tab. An empty line, for example, or if your format doesn't actually use tabs.

You have two options:

1. skip rows with fewer columns than you need:

   ```
   for row in reader:
       if len(row) < 2:
           continue
       writer.writerow((row[1], row[0]))
   ```
2. fix your delimiter to match the actual file content:

   ```
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
   ```

   you could use the [`csv.Sniffer()` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) to try and automate delimiter selection, if you have more than one file to process, and these files are not all following the same CSV dialect.

Comment: It might be simpler to simply `.split()`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: perhaps, but that won't solve the problem of possibly empty lines or lines with 1 column only.

Comment: I just had a thought - why not just `writer.writerow(row[::-1])` since the idea is to reverse the order of the columns.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I  think the problem is due to large number of entries in the csv file. In small files it works perfectly.

Comment: @karu: That's not a problem at all for the `csv` module, which processes your file line by line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, fine

Comment: @karu: That's a different error indeed, and one of your lines is too long. At least one line is longer than 128kb, that's way too big.

Answer (score 1):

Since all you want to do is write the file in reverse order, just write the same row back, but in reverse; like this:

```
 writer.writerow(row[::-1])
```

A negative index starts from the right, and a negative step value (the third argument in the slice syntax) will simply reverse the object.

This will stop the error you are seeing now, and in case you have rows columns that are not 2, they will also be written in reverse.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akallararajappan/corpus/dg.py", line 7, in <module>
    for row in reader:
Error: field larger than field limit (131072)

Comment: Do you have any quote characters in your file? Try reading it with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`, if this doesn't fix it - add `csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)` before your `with` statement (don't forget to `import sys` first).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I suspect something else is wrong with the actual file when the OP has to handle 128kb lines..

Comment: Martijn could this be some encoding issue?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: if an UTF encoding is used, I don't think so.